# Script to merge feature branch into master and create a PR

Tags: git, github

My requirement is to write a script to merge my feature branch into master. To do this, I am cutting another branch from the feature-branch (lets say merge-branch), merging master into it and creating a PR. I am following the below steps:

- `git checkout master`
- `git pull origin master`
- `git checkout feature-branch`
- `git pull origin feature-branch`
- `git checkout -b merge-branch`
- Make version changes and commit them
- `git merge --no-commit master` - I am using this command to check for any potential merge conflicts before creating the PR
- `git push origin merge-branch`
- And then finally using github api, create a PR to merge merge-branch into master branch

The issue that I am facing is: After creation of the PR, I am on branch merge-branch and it says `All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.`
I assume this is because `git merge --no-commit master` stops before creating the commit. So, I was thinking of using `git merge master` instead so that I do not get the above prompt after running my script.
However, I cannot test out this approach because I do not have rights to those branches yet.

Is the above approach and steps correct, or is there an easier alternative to check for merge conflicts before the creation of PR?

Comment: This looks like `git merge feature-branch` but with nine extra steps.